# If $a, b, x, y$ are rational and $(ay - bx)^2 + 4(a - x)(b - y) = 0$, then $1 - ab$ and $1 - xy$ are squares of rationals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you help me solve this problem?

> If $a, b, x, y$ are rational numbers such that $(ay - bx)^2 + 4(a - x)(b - y) = 0$, then $1 - ab$ and $1 - xy$ are squares of rational numbers.

I tried calculating $(ay - bx)^2$ cancelling terms etc. but couldn’t figure out what to do next. I also tried assuming $ab = 1 - r^2$ etc. and “work backwards” but still no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: Well, it is only true if you assume $a,b,x,y$ are rational.

Comment: It looks like a discriminant to a quadratic equation: $$\alpha u^2+\beta u-\gamma=0\tag1$$ where $\alpha=a-x, \beta=ay-bx, \gamma=b-y.$ Not sure if that helps, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying out we obtain a quadratic equation in $y$, namely
$$
y^2a^2 + 2y( - abx - 2a + 2x) + b(4a + bx^2 - 4x)=0.
$$
The usual formula for a quadratic equation shows that $y$ is rational if and only if $\sqrt{1-ab}$ is rational. But this just means, that $1-ab=r^2$ for some rational number $r$.
Actually, the two solutions are
$$
y=\frac{\pm 2(a-x)\sqrt{ 1- ab} + abx + 2a - 2x}{a^2}
$$

Exchanging the roles of $x,y$ and $a,b$ we also obtain the second claim.